# Bypassing Spring Security Filter

Tags: spring-security

My implementation of `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` overrides `getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal()`. In a certain circumstance, I'd like to bypass this security filter.

To do so, I returned `null` as per the [Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.html#getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) **[EDIT]**  **and that worked**.

> Note that this will not affect cases where the principal returned by
>   getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) is
>   null, when the chain will still proceed as normal.

Comment: Could you tell us more about how it failed? By looking at the code in `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`, the documentation describes exactly what's implemented there.

Comment: After returning `null`, the logger spit out `No pre-authenticated principal found in request`. And then, it appears that my OAuth Request (reason I wanted to bypass security filter) failed with `401 Unauthorized` error.

Comment: If you take a look at the class, you can see that after emitting that log message `doAuthenticate()` returns to `doFilter()` where the execution continues with the invokation of the next filter in the chain (`chain.doFilter()`). That's exactly what you wanted. Which means the 401 you get is caused by something else. I guess it's a result of some other auth filter trying and failing to authenticate the request.